# Externalize Configuration for Android Integration / Functional Tests

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, integration-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I'm moving to the [Gradle plugin for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) and refactoring some integration tests.  Some of these tests have code like the following:

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    _client = new Client("https://test02.server.com", "password");
}
```

I want to externalize the URL and password so that they can be driven from a Jenkins build.  I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. The tests will all be run using the Gradle Android plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't speak for the Jenkins part.

Ignoring Jenkins, here are a couple of Gradle for Android approaches:

1. Put those values in resources, such as string resources, and have replacement versions of those resources in different build types for the different types of testing. You can see that in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloBuildType), where I have different versions of a string resource for debug vs. release, plus have a custom mezzanine build type.
2. Put those values in `BuildConfig`, with replacement versions for the different build types for your different types of testing. You can see that in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloBuildConfig), which extends the previous one, where adding to `BuildConfig` is done in the `build.gradle` file via `buildConfigField` directives. While in this sample, the values to go in `buildConfigField` are hard-coded, they could be driven by environment variables, properties files, etc.

Comment: I think second solution fits very well since Jenkins will provide build variable Gregg can reference it in gradle build

Comment: I went with #2.  Worked great.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gregg: FYI, with the 0.8.0 version of the Gradle for Android plugin, you can replace existing values of `BuildConfig`. In the sample I linked to, right now, I create the `mezzanine` build type (cloned from `release`), then define `SERVER_URL` for the `mezzanine` build type, then define `SERVER_URL` for the `release` build type. That's simpler now: a `BuildConfig` for the same value (e.g., `SERVER_URL`) replaces the earlier version. My next update to the repo (and book) will show defining `SERVER_URL` on `release`, cloning `mezzanine`, and overriding the original `SERVER_URL` in `mezzanine`.

Comment: What book?  do you have a link?